# Config file in payment section in magento2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have an extension that has some config fields in the `payment` section. The extension does **not** supply a payment method, I just want to have the settings in the *Payment Methods* section.

The `system.xml`looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="321" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <resource>Xxx_Fee::config</resource>
            <group id="fee_config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label> Fee Configuration</label>
                <field id="fee_enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Cod Fee Functionality</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="fee_type" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Fee Type</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Source\HandlingType</source_model>
                </field>
          </group>
        </section>
      </system>
    </config>
```

So everything's fine until now. Now I want to have a default value, so I create `config.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <fee_config>    
                <fee_enabled>1</fee_enabled>           
<fee_title>CodFeeAmount</fee_title>
            </config>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

When I try to open the configuration, I see nothing and get the following error in `system.log`:

> Payment model name is not provided in config!

How to solve it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Your not provided the payment name in model

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
      <system>
        <section id="payment">
          <group id="myextension" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="99" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>MyExtension</label>
            <field id="activate_export" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
              <label>Export Orders</label>
              <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>            
              <config_path>payment/myextension/activate_export</config_path>
            </field>
          </group>
        </section>
      </system>
</config>
```

System.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
  <default>
    <payment>
      <myextension>
        <activate_export>1</activate_export>
        <model>Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment\File</model>
      </myextension>
    </payment>
  </default>
</config>
```

You need to create model file,

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\Filename;

class Filename extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

    protected $_code = "myextension";
    protected $_isOffline = true;

    public function isAvailable(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    ) {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my updated answer you missed the model file please try above and let me know if it's working for you

Comment: does not see any changes..........@Jeeva Chezhiyan

Comment: Did you try above code?

Comment: still not get config values

Comment: try this module creator https://mage2gen.com/.. you will get some idea

Comment: @PriyaM https://mage2gen.com/load/cbfb1b5a-603c-4535-9da3-6db28e083766/ click this link I have created

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding title in your config.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
  <default>
    <payment>
      <myextension>
        <activate_export>1</activate_export>
        <title>Your Payment Method Name</title>
      </myextension>
    </payment>
  </default>
</config>
```

**Note:** Make sure you clear your entry from `setup_module` table and run `setup:upgrade` command again.

Check if you see the title record in `core_config_data`

Comment: still not get default values @Priyank